# Should I go for a run before buying running shoes?

Tags: running, running-shoes, jogging

I was recently told that one should buy running shoes at the end of the day because our feet will swell over the course of the day. The thinking was if you bought them at the start of the day you might get shoes that are too small. This made me think that perhaps a daily jog might influence foot size (and thus shoe size) as well.

**Before buying shoes, should I go for a run to get my feet to the right size?**

Answer (score 2):

A good shoe will adapt to your foot over time of using it. You want it to be comfortable at all times during running.

I would stick with the suggestion of buying it at the end of the day. A walk into town should warm your feet up to their normal working size and shape.